# Object Not Found error for simple php script

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, http-status-code-404

Every time I hit the submit button to process this code in my webpage it goes to the Object Not Found (404 error) page. It has happened in a few of my scripts and i don't know the source of the problem of whether its my localhost(Xampp) or my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    require "dbc.php"; //Connection to database
    //the textfield input to be saved
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['assign_id']);
    $id   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    //the mysql query to process the textfield input
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET docID='$assign_id' WHERE id='$id'");
//normal statement to let the user know that the changes have been made.    
    echo "Doctor ID Successfully Assigned for Patient ID : $name ";
    echo "<p>Refresh page to view changes.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet references `$assign_id` in the query, but it's not defined. Is it set earlier? Or did you mean `$name` instead of `$assign_id` in this query: `"UPDATE users SET docID='$assign_id' WHERE id='$id'"`

Comment: So is that code run (and then 404s), or does the submit form 404 before loading your code? In which case, we'd need to see the submit form, too, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$assign_id` in your query, where you get the `$_POST['assign_id']` earlier and store it to `$name`.

Try changing `$assign_id` in your query to `$name`.
or
Try changing you variable `$name` to `$assign_id`.

**EDIT**

Another thing to check, is the file `dbc.php` in the same directory as this file?

**EDIT 2**

Post the contents of your `apache2/error.log` file. That will show what file was not found.

**EDIT 3**

Post the code for you `<form>` opening tag. What is your `action` set to? Does the action file actually exist?

Comment: if it wasn't, then the require would fail and you'd get a php error, not just "404". Unless, of course, there's a custom 500 error handling defined, but is missing...

Comment: Glad I could be of some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

404 is an HTTP error code, it has nothing to do (directly) with PHP.

It means that the server is not able to locate a file that matches with your request.

Essentially, it looks like you're requesting http://yourdomain.com/path/to/script.php when you submit your form, but the /path/to/script.php file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

When pressing submit on a form, the server tries to find the 'action' of the form. You should check that this action contains a valid filename in a correct path.

Answer (score 0):

When pressing submit on a form, the server tries to find the 'action' of the form. You should check that this action contains a valid filename in a correct path.Always it shows error..